# My code returns HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, screen-scraping, urllib

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myUrl = "https://mee6.xyz/levels/159962941502783488"

uClient = uReq(myUrl)
pageHtml = uClient.read()
print("pageHtml)
```

I'm trying to access a page to start scraping it, but it replies that the HTTP is forbidden, I looked up other results, but they don't match up with how I'm doing my code

Comment: Can you access the url from your web browser? Error 403 means that the resource (or web page) that you’re trying to access is forbidden. First see if you can load the website from a normal browser and check there’s no misspellings or mistakes in the url.

Comment: Also look at this tutorial, and consider using ‘urllib2’ as it is a very straightforward and useful library.

Comment: URL opens and works, the code worked for another website as well. Just with the discord url it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are being blocked because of your User Agent. Try spoofing your User Agent like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myUrl = "https://mee6.xyz/levels/159962941502783488"

req = Request(
    myUrl, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

uClient = uReq(req)
pageHtml = uClient.read()
print(pageHtml)
```

Comment: Is that reading all types of user agents? If so, how do you select individual versions.

Comment: This is setting it to pretend to be Chrome on Windows 10. It looks like Chrome on Windows 10 is allowed by the server so it lets it in. If you want you could try another common user agent just go to http://www.whatsmyua.info/ in the browser you want to impersonate and copy the user-agent string.