# My HTTP Request to the Discord API Only Returns Forbidden (403)

Tags: python, sockets, web, https, http-status-code-403

I have tried changing my token, rechecking the url, rechecking my User-Agent, and re-formatting my HTTP. I do not know what else to do. I am following the documentation here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference . I have tried to follow it to a tee, but I still get "Forbidden". I used the User-Agent found here: [My code returns HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746909/my-code-returns-http-error-403-forbidden)

```py
import socket, ssl
token = 'NzMyMzQ1MTcwNjk1MTU5ODU3.XxG68A.RednSTamtbmFf7e4aXmtoZiwiQc'
HOST = "discord.com"
PORT = 443
t = f'''
GET /api/guilds/702627382091186318/channels HTTP/1.0\r\n
 Authentication: Bot {token}\r\n
 Host: discord.com\r\n
 User-Agent: User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36\r\n
 Content-length: 500
 \r\n
 '''
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOST)
s_sock.connect((HOST, 443))
s_sock.sendall(t.encode())

f = s_sock.recv(7000).decode()
print(f)

s_sock.close()import socket, ssl
token = 'NzMyMzQ1MTcwNJk5mTU5ODu3.XAG32A.rADnSTamtbmFf7e4aXmtoZiwiQc'
HOST = "discord.com"
PORT = 443
t = f'''
GET /api/guilds/702627382091186318/channels HTTP/1.0\r\n
 Authentication: Bot {token}\r\n
 Host: discord.com\r\n
 User-Agent: User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36\r\n
 Content-length: 500
 \r\n
 '''
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=HOST)
s_sock.connect((HOST, 443))
s_sock.sendall(t.encode())

f = s_sock.recv(7000).decode()
print(f)

s_sock.close()
```

**Output**:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: cloudflare
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 19:22:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 151
Connection: close
CF-RAY: 5b4654647edc0de2-IAD
cf-request-id: 03ffd312c700000de2ff233200000001

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The token used is not valid

Comment: This is [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953254/how-to-format-http-request-to-discord-api) not a valid HTTP request in the first place. Please stop guessing of how HTTP works but either use a library for it or read the standards.

Comment: Hi Steffen, could you please send me the up-to-date standards? I will 100% read them start to finish. Thanks for the constructive feedback!

Comment: Please start with [Wikipedia: HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). The necessary standards are mentioned at the beginning. Warning: these are far from trivial and short. HTTP is more complex than it looks.

Comment: Dude!! Why are you trying to replicate the HTTP protocol by yourself?? https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html

Comment: httplib is already VERY LOW LEVEL, for handling HTTP (imagine that what you are trying to do is even lower). Use requests module https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/